# Need script to parse file and then convert to mqtt message

Tags: shell, awk, mqtt, netcat

First off, I'm not a programmer but I've managed to do a few things in the past.  Much more of a hacker than anything.

I'm using Mochad to interface with my X10 receiver and I want to take the output from Mochad, parse a few pieces from it and then send that as a MQTT message so I can use it with my home automation hub Home Assistant.  This is what the output of Mochad looks like:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nc localhost 1099
12/30 17:37:18 Rx RF HouseUnit: B3 Func: On
12/30 17:37:19 Rx RF HouseUnit: B4 Func: Off
12/30 17:37:21 Rx RF HouseUnit: B6 Func: On
12/30 17:37:23 Rx RF HouseUnit: B6 Func: On
12/30 17:37:24 Rx RF HouseUnit: B7 Func: Off
12/30 17:37:25 Rx RF HouseUnit: B8 Func: On
12/30 17:37:27 Rx RF HouseUnit: B2 Func: On
```

Notice that I am using net cat to view this data.  A new line is only added when an X10 signal is detected.  I'd like to grab the HouseUnit values (ex B3) and the Func values (ex On).  I can do this easily with awk but I can't figure out how to do this from the netcat output.

Once these two values or parsed, I would like to publish them to MQTT message like this:

```
mosquitto_pub -t /X10/B3 -m On
```

After this the routine would wait for another message and just keep doing this procedure for each new message received from Mochad.

Is there an easy way to do this via a commandline script?  I've written for loops that can do these sort of things but I'm struggling getting the net cat output into the for loop.

I'm doing all of this on a RaspberryPi3 with the HASSBian distro (Raspbian modified for Home Assistant).  Any help is greatly appreciated.

*EDIT* Anyone else able to help?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you want:

```
nc localhost 1099 | awk ' { system("mosquitto_pub -t /X10/"$6" -m "$8) } '
```

This takes the output of `nc` and pipes it into `awk` which then calls `mosquitto_pub` for each line.

EDIT: Tested with the following:

nc -l localhost 1099 < nc-test

Where nc-test is a text file with the example data shown in the question.

p.s. as a rule MQTT topics should not start with a leading / as it adds a extra null level of to the topic tree.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am not getting any output or messages sent with this.

Comment: works fine if I use nc to cat a file with the same output to a version of nc listening on a port as the input since I don't have the same source of data. e.g. `nc -l localhost 1099 | awk ....` and `nc localhost 1099 < test.txt`

Comment: I tried adding the -l option and I'm still not getting anything.  Is there an easy way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I tried doing nc localhost 1099 | awk ' { print $0 } '   and I still get no output.

Comment: The -l is only to make that instance of nc listen (because that's the easiest way to get it to wait for input), you don't need it

Comment: Maybe try `stdbuf -oL nc localhost 1099 ...` in case you are suffering from buffering.

Comment: Correction, this is working.  Sort of.  I do get some messages going through but not all of them.  I'm not sure what is happening, but I am seeing at least one of my devices getting through but not all of them.  And the one device I do see doesn't show up every time it is triggered.  It's like Mochad events are sometimes missed.  Any idea on why that might be happening?

Comment: Any chance on other things to test to see why this is not working?

Comment: I had to add -W interactive to get it to work but it works now!